# Finding the limit as $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits

[image]

This is how I proceeded with this question but the answer in my book is given to be 0. Is my method correct? Please help so that I can correct myself in case of any mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No notice that 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$
and not $\frac{\sin \frac 1 x}{\frac 1x}$.

Now since $|\sin\frac{1}{x^k}|\leq 1$ then 
$$\lim_{x\to0}x^k\sin\frac{1}{x^k}=0$$
so the given limit is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$0\leq\left|x^k\sin \frac{1}{x^k}\right|\leq\left|x^k\right|\xrightarrow[x\rightarrow0]{}0$$

Comment: But what about the result that :limit as x approaches zero sinx/x is 1?

Comment: But when $x\rightarrow0, \ \frac1x\rightarrow\infty$ and therefore you cannot use taht result on $\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac1x}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1\text{ but } \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin (1/x)}{1/x} = 0.
$$
The latter equality can be seen by squeezing: $\sin(1/x)$ remains between $1$ and $-1$, so $\dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}$ remains between $\dfrac{1}{1/x}$ and $\dfrac{-1}{1/x}$, both of which approach $0$.

Comment: The very first limit ought to read $x\to0$, not $x\to\infty$.